# git undo does not revert file back to its original state

Tags: git, command-line

I have created a new repository and it had a Readme.md file added to it. Now this was added on the remote repository. Then I cloned the remote to my local machine and added some .ignore file and staged the file in the master branch. Later on I decided that I wanted to revert only the README back to its original state while commiting the other files so I first staged and committed only the .ignore files and then I tried the following commands to undo changes to the README:

`git reset HEAD README.md`

`git checkout -- README.md`

When those did not work I tried out

`git checkout HEAD -- README.md`

`git reset --hard <commit id> README.md`

`git reset --hard HEAD README.md`

`git reflog README.md`

`git checkout <commit id> README.md`

`git checkout README.md`

None of these seem to have worked. When I hit the command `git status` I see the following output:-

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   README.md

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Can anyone help here? How do I get the README file to not show as modified and revert it back to what its state is on the remote server?

Comment: What is the output of `git diff`, and how does it compare to your desired contents of `README.md`?

Comment: These are typically due to line-ending differences (LF vs CR-LF) on Windows vs non-Windows systems, as controlled by `core.autocrlf`, `core.eol`, `.gitattributes`, and so on. Search for articles about these topics.

Comment: @ScottWeldon I see something like this at the end of the file `+
 Happy coding!
\ No newline at end of file`

Comment: To directly test for what both @torek and I are getting at: please post whether `git diff --ignore-space-at-eol` gives you any output. If it does not, then there is an issue with your line endings.

Comment: Or for simplicity, post the output of both `git diff --stat` and `git diff --ignore-space-at-eol --stat`. Please [edit] this information into your post.